# Is it possible to calculate standard deviation from known confidence interval?

Tags: statistics, mean, standard-deviation

I have a value of a confidence interval for a parameter and I want to calculate the standard deviation, t value, and standard error of the parameter. Is it possible to calculate these statistics while having only the confidence interval (I don't know sample size)?

Comment: This doesn't look like a question about programming. Try asking here instead: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics / mathematics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot calculate any of those statistics from just the confidence interval alone. The construction of a confidence interval requires the estimate of the parameter (e.g. the sample mean is an estimate of the population mean), the critical value from an assumed distribution, and the standard error. Without knowing two of the above three statistics, you cannot calculate the last.

Comment: I have parameter value and its confidence interval. Is it possible to determine standard deviation and t-stat value of the parameter?

Comment: No you can’t. You need either the t-critical value or the stand error to find the other one from the confidence interval.